# Moving data from the controller to a view if it's not already in a model or fixture with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/igogocAw/1/edit

I've got an array in a controller but it's not bound to a model or part of a fixture. I want to get it into the view, so do I need to create a model for it first? You can see the full code in that jsbin, but here's what my controller looks like. You can see I already tried to go down that route with the commented out damageTaken code.

```
actions: {
    findDamage: function(){
        attackId = this.get('chosenAttack');
        var typeresult = this.store.find('type', attackId);
        typeresult.then(function(val1){
            var attackingType = val1.get('name');
            var damageModArray = val1.get('damageModifiers').toArray();
            //var defenseTypeCount = damageModArray.length;
            damageModArray.forEach(function(dmg){
                console.log(attackingType + " type damages " + dmg.get("name") + ": " + dmg.get("modifier"));
                //works, now to get this into the view...
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy, just make sure damageModArray is a property of the controller, like :

```
App.YourController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   damageMod : Em.A([]),
   ...
```

Whenever you need to set the value:

```
actions: {
findDamage: function(){
    var self = this;
    attackId = this.get('chosenAttack');
    var typeresult = this.store.find('type', attackId);
    typeresult.then(function(val1){
        var attackingType = val1.get('name');
        self.damageMod.pushObjects(val1.get('damageModifiers').toArray());

    });
}
```

Then on the html/view (under that controller), you can refer the values by just

```
{{#each damageMod}} //for interation
```

Comment: I can get the name to show up, but not the modifier value. I'm trying to get the corresponding number to show up. I tried doing the puhsObjects idea inside of the loop that iterates through the array, but it didn't work. My ideal output is: user selects Rock, view shows table with the left column being Rock, Paper, Scissors and the right column being 1, 0.5, 2. Here's my updated emberbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/igogocAw/4/edit

Comment: I'm not a big fan of ember-data, not sure how the relationship model works. Two comments about your code though. [1] You can do self.damageMod.pushObjects(val1.get('damageModifiers')); //without the .toArray(), in order to keep the "class" model of it. [2] You can just do self.damageMod.forEach(...), do not need to .toArray()